# Disappearing object animation not immediate

Tags: animation, objects, keyframes, properties, visibility

Despite keyframeing the objects at different times, they seem to simultaneously spawn and disappear at the same time, when running animation. How do I get these objects to appear and disappear as per keyframe? Thanks

Edit: without the snow material, the objects indeed do disappear as intended, yet with the snow material, most of the objects simultaneously disappear and disappear.

[Disappear tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tzSesvjEEds)

[image]

Examples:

During running
[image]

When paused (Before disappearing keyframe)
[image]

```
        (After disappearing keyframe)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong on my side, objects appear and disappear as per key framed.

If you talk about the volumetric shader flickering during playback but not frame  by frame, that's just because the volumetric is displayed step by step in material view and Eevee, it's basically displaying slices of volume layers on top of each other.
It just needs time to render, but playback is too fast for that. So if you really want to see volumetrics fully done in playback, you can reduce the volumetrics render quality (like bigger tile size and fewer samples). It will give you uglier volumes, but maybe it will at least be fast enough to see them fully in playback.

[image]

It might work but be ugly, or it won't. Either way, accept that you won't see volumetrics accurately in viewport playback. But it will look fine in render

If you talk about how you don't see the object's outline during or after playback, that's because in Blender you can't select objects that are hidden. Since your object gets hidden during your animation, you lose selection. But if you go in solid mode, you can see it there on time when you want it.

Comment: How do I get the volumetric shader to appear and disappear together with the objects they were assigned to?

Comment: It just needs time to render. It doesn't have enough time to do it on playback, so either you reduce the Volumetrics render quality (like bigger tile size and fewer samples), or you accept that you won't see volumetrics accurately in viewport playback. But it will look fine in render.